# Rethinkdb on Heroku

Tags: heroku, docker-compose, rethinkdb

I tried searching on the web for a tutorial to install rethinkdb on heroku but was not satisfied with the tutorial provided. Can anyone suggest a step by guide to install rethinkdb via compose or dockerhero as a database for heroku nodejs app? I don't know ruby or python.

Answer (score 0):

Only this one for now https://docs.dockhero.io/tutorials/rethinkdb.html
I also consider using docker for proper deployment.